# Slow mysql query including Left Join and Selects

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, left-join, query-optimization

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS null as `rows` , 
   (SELECT count(*) FROM `ci_user_smiley` where post_id = P.post_id) as smiley, 
   (SELECT count(*) FROM `ci_user_tag` where post_id = P.post_id) as tag, 
   (SELECT count(*) FROM `ci_comments` where post_id = P.post_id) as comment_count, 
    P.*, U.point_1 + U.point_2 + U.point_3 as `total`, F.*, Fi.*, U.* 

FROM `ci_posts` P 

LEFT JOIN `ci_users` U 
     ON P.`user_id` = U.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `ci_filters` F
     ON P.`filter` = F.filter_id 
LEFT JOIN `ci_files` Fi 
     ON P.file = Fi.file_id 

WHERE P.`approve` = 1 AND U.active = 1 AND P.post_type = 'post-color'
     AND 1 ORDER BY P.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

This query takes 5 minutes to execute, How can I improve it!? Is that because of LEFT JOINs or Selects?
Notice that Some of tables has got between 10K to 100k rows
I appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: I would recommend that you learn how to format a question.  After this, I would recommend that you add indices to the join columns.

Comment: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS null as rows` is weird. It just gives a NULL column in your result set called `rows`  The `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` item is a modifier on the whole query, not the row.  You may wish to omit it unless you know you need it.

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen thanks for the hint

Comment: @OllieJones that's needed and will be used in other part of code. BTW thanks for edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to consider to optimize this.

Overall, read http://use-the-index-luke.com/

First: Your subqueries like this one will be faster with an index on `post_id`.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM ci_user_smiley where post_id = P.post_id
```

Second: A wise programmer strenuously avoids using `SELECT ... table.*` or any form of SELECT column wildcard `*` character, instead giving a list of needed columns for the query. The query planner can often optimize a query when it knows it can omit some columns from the result set.

Third:  This is a notorious query antipattern.

```
 SELECT lots of columns
   FROM table JOIN table .... lots of tables
  ORDER BY column
  LIMIT small number
```

Why? It tells the query planner to generate an enormous result set, sort it, and then discard all but `small number` rows of it.  This is wasteful.

You may do better with a query containing something like this

```
 WHERE p.post_id IN (SELECT p.post_id 
                       FROM ci_posts p
                       JOIN `ci_users` u 
                                 ON p.`user_id` = u.`user_id`
                      WHERE p.approve = 1
                        AND p.post_type = 'post-color'
                        AND u.active = 1
                      ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 20)
```

The `IN` clause fetches just the twenty interesting `post_id` values. That will limit the load / sort / discard operation to just the `post_id` and `post_date` columns, which will be far cheaper. A compound index on `ci_posts (post_type, approve, post_date, user_id)` will help a lot.

I've used `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` because the `u.active = 1` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into a `JOIN` anyway.

Comment: Otherwise nice answer, however their limit is based on active users, so you would have to JOIN in your subselect first.

Comment: @DRapp you're right. Nice catch. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @OllieJones  As I'm not a mysql expert I should ask how can I add index to subqueries?
The Limit on posts are using for pagination.
BTW thanks for Perfect points!

Comment: You don't add indexes to queries or subqueries. You add them to tables, so the MySQL query planner (a software module) can use them. There's usually no harm to having several indexes on a table, as long as they help queries.

Comment: Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`, it optimizes poorly.  Instead do the equivalent `JOIN ( SELECT ...)`.